# Use nested fields in kibana panels

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I tried to display a Kibana dashboard and it works well. Unfortunately, when I want to add a pie chart (or another representation) containing the countries of the companies locations, I have an empty panel.

I'm able to use the kibana queries to filter on a specific country but I'm not able to display a panel with nested documents.

My mapping (I have to use nested fields because a company can have several locations):

```
{
  "settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "company" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
        "website" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
        "employees" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
        "type": { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
        "locations" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "city" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
            "country" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
            "coordinates" : { "type" : "geo_point", "store" : "yes" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do you know how could I display panel with nested objects? Is it implemented?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: I assume you tried using "locations.country" as the selected field in a term panel?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing one parameter ("include_in_parent": true) in your mapping. 
The correct mapping should be:

```
{
  "settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "company" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
        "website" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
        "employees" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
        "type": { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
        "locations" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "include_in_parent": true,
          "properties" : {
            "city" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
            "country" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
            "coordinates" : { "type" : "geo_point", "store" : "yes" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: On kibana 3 adding include_in_parent: true does not make nested objects like one above location.country get mapped by kibana.

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly a Kibana bug. The facet query generated by Kibana is missing the "nested" field to indicate this.